# Set Active Tab Pane in Emberjs Handelbars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a tab-pane (bootstrap) in my emberjs application and the first tab should be active from the beginning. I found some sites where it is possible in handelbars to get the index of an each loop like `{{#if @first}}` but it didn't work.

What is the easiest solution to this?

Code looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  {{#each model.languages}}
    <li><a href="#{{this.language}}" data-toggle="tab">{{this.language}}</a</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<div class="localized-system-info tab-content">
  {{#each model.systemLanguages}}
    <!-- forms -->
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an arbitrary number of tabs, or is it a fixed constant?

Comment: arbitary, but this shouldn't matter, I always have one fix tab and only need to set active to the first one

Answer (score 0):

If your first tab is always the one selected, then you can do something like this:

```
// controller.js
languages: function() {
    // Assuming the languages are already ordered
    var isFirst = true;
    return this.get('model.languages').map(function(language) {
        var obj = {
            language: language,
            isFirst: isFirst
        };

        isFirst = false;

        return obj;
    });
}.property('model.languages.[]')
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each languages}}
    {{#if isFirst}}

    {{else}}

    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

This should allow you to implement any custom functionality for the first language, but not the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer but I am really struggling with  solutions like this. In my opinion this active state shouldn't be saved in the object. It's only a view-thing, without any logic.
Sad that handlebars is so bad and ruins emberjs :(